# Xcode 15.1 - Localizable strings used in previews are automatically added to .xcstrings

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode15, xcstrings

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes .xcstrings files for localization. However, I've encountered an issue since upgrading to Xcode 15.1. Specifically, localizable strings that are used in previews are now being automatically added to the .xcstrings files. This behavior wasn't present in previous versions.
Do you know how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: I have the same question as well, but I fear this is just a bug / regression.